# PHP preg replace whitehat characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

**This regex keep letters and numbers and remove the rest**

It works as expected:

```
$content = preg_replace('~\P{Xan}+~u', '', $string);
```

**I try to whitehat some characters but it does not work**

I try to whitehat dot, comma, minus and space below:

```
$content = preg_replace('~\P{Xan}.,- +~u', '', $string);
```

Instead it allows everything, even the strange characters.

How can I make it work like before but just whitehat some special characters?

Comment: [`[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+`](https://regex101.com/r/xH0dT3/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, PCRE in PHP does not support [character class intersection](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html), nor [subtraction](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html).

You can do this with a negated character class and a reverse shorthand Unicode category class:

```
'~[^\p{Xan}., +-]+~u'
```

The `\P{Xan}` = `[^\p{Xan}]`, but we can add more characters to the negated character class and the meaning will be *match characters other than `\p{Xan}`, `.`, `,`, space, `+`, and `-`.

Another way is to restrict the generic subpattern with a lookahead (but do not forget to put that subpattern into a group as the quantifier should be applied to the resulting `(?:(?![., +-])\P{Xan})` construct):

```
'~(?:(?![., +-])\P{Xan})+~u'
```